# Using .map in return() to import a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone tell me how I can import a bunch of components using .map?   Something like this...

````
import Welcome from 'Welcome.jsx';
import Services from 'Services.jsx';

const Index = props => {
  const myComponents = ['Welcome', 'Services'];

  return (
    <div>
      {myComponents.map((componentName, index) => (
        <div key={index}> />
          <{componentName} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Maybe you want to look into `React.createElement`? However, I would probably still list them without string quotes, and then just render `<ComponentName />` instead (and use the argument with PascalCasing, as the convention suggests)

Comment: Shouldn't myComponents be an array of components?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Still trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't go by their names. Use the components (function values) themselves in your array:

```
import Welcome from 'Welcome.jsx';
import Services from 'Services.jsx';

const Index = props => {
  const myComponents = [Welcome, Services];

  return (
    <div>
      {myComponents.map((AnyComponent, index) => (
        <div key={index}> />
          <AnyComponent />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try @Bergi solution. However you can also go full generic and use `require` to import and generate components.

```
const myComponents = ['Welcome', 'Services'].map((name) => require(`${name}.jsx`).default);

const Index = props => {
   return (
      <div>
         {myComponents.map((component, index) => {
            const Component = component;

            return (
               <div key={index}>
                  <Component />
               </div>
            );
         })}
     </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nice.  Will try this too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can take it one step further by *lazy-loading* the components:

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
const AnotherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./AnotherComponent'));

const MyComponent () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <section>
          <OtherComponent />
          <AnotherComponent />
        </section>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

More info on: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html